# Listing all effects for a transaction

Tags: transactions, stellar-laboratory

I’m having a bit of a trouble listing effects for one transaction record.

When I list (e.g. on stellar laboratory) all TransactionForAccount, I get only limited number of records. I understand it. It needs to be paged. So I read all records and than do another page query via `_links:next:href`. Once there are no recors (or lees than a limit) I know, that is the last page.

But if I follow the “effects” link from single transaction record there is a array of effects and again next page href `_links:next:href` but that next page gives the same array of effects.

How do I list all the effects for a single transaction? How do I know I'm on the last page?

**EDIT**

It looks like the problem is only when viewing through `stellar laboratory`

for example see effects for transaction `1beb1ffd69ed279fb46cdc691e56c316241cce3e3fbaaa862dc1fbf442d7779c`
[Link here.](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=effects&endpoint=for_transaction&values=eyJvcmRlciI6ImFzYyIsImxpbWl0IjoiIiwiY3Vyc29yIjoiIiwidHJhbnNhY3Rpb24iOiIxYmViMWZmZDY5ZWQyNzlmYjQ2Y2RjNjkxZTU2YzMxNjI0MWNjZTNlM2ZiYWFhODYyZGMxZmJmNDQyZDc3NzljIn0%3D&network=public)
There are 2 effects (as expected).

when click at link `_links:next:href` I get the same page. When accessing it it directly, returned JSON has indeed empty effects

Comment: I'm seeing additional bug, whereby the link in lab opens in testnet instead of live. I saw your bug report and added my finding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a bug in laboratory, if you just list effects using horizon endpoint - you won't get same effects on next page, it will be empty.

Another way of doing that is to decode `result_meta_xdr` for particular transaction.
Here's your example [transaction in laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=transactions&endpoint=single&values=eyJ0cmFuc2FjdGlvbiI6IjFiZWIxZmZkNjllZDI3OWZiNDZjZGM2OTFlNTZjMzE2MjQxY2NlM2UzZmJhYWE4NjJkYzFmYmY0NDJkNzc3OWMifQ%3D%3D&network=public).

Now click through to `result_meta_xdr` and you will get to [this page](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAEAAAAAwD0r0UAAAAAAAAAAC5zLGw%2BM%2FxWxWJT66%2FVpZakjDlDFSzaK62isqsIYjbJAAAALPBIJ%2FAA7A4XAAAAAgAAAAAAAAABAAAAAIQ%2FAS7GRUBBd96ykumKKUFE92%2BoiwRuJ7KXuvPwwTQWAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQD0sC8AAAAAAAAAAC5zLGw%2BM%2FxWxWJT66%2FVpZakjDlDFSzaK62isqsIYjbJAAAANKdTowAA7A4XAAAAAgAAAAAAAAABAAAAAIQ%2FAS7GRUBBd96ykumKKUFE92%2BoiwRuJ7KXuvPwwTQWAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwD0sC8AAAAAAAAAADt0GB0X4TfO14Hx5gkxZOORukePiFQFo4TFA5te03hjABx0y0DawdkACH3XAADaYQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQD0sC8AAAAAAAAAADt0GB0X4TfO14Hx5gkxZOORukePiFQFo4TFA5te03hjABx0w4nPRskACH3XAADaYQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&type=TransactionMeta), which should list all effects for the transaction. Decoding it manually from XDR format saves you HTTP request.